# geodesics in hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be the Poincare ball model of the Hyperbolic space, and let $\zeta \in T_0M$. In my lecture notes it is claimed that $$c(t)=\tanh(\Vert \zeta \Vert t )\zeta/\Vert \zeta \Vert$$ is the geodesic that satisfies the initial conditions $c(0)=0$ and $c'(0)=\zeta$.

I know that lines through the origin are geodesics, and this is clearly a line through the origin that also satisfies the initial conditions. But my question is, where does this particular parametrization come from? How can I verify if it is correct?

Comment: Have you tried to check what it means for the velocity vector to have constant length in the hyperbolic metric?

Comment: Hm. I'm probably doing it wrong. If we just start by $c(t)=r(t)\zeta$, the velocity vector is $r'(t) \zeta$. Plugged in to the metric this gives me $(2r'(t)/(1-r(t)^2))^2$, which should be constant...? @TedShifrin

Comment: So, does this check with $\tanh(at)$?

Comment: Oh, you're right, $\tanh(at)$ *does* make it constant! Thanks! @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1):

Begin with the two dimensional upper half plane. One type of geodesic is, with constant $A,$
$$  x = A, \; \;  y = e^t  $$

The other type is a semicircle, now with constant $B > 0,$
$$ x = A + B \tanh t \; , \; \; y = B \operatorname{sech} t  $$

The simplest way to map these, back and forth, to the unit disc is to regard the $y$ direction as imaginary, then use the Moebius transformations 
$$  \frac{z+i}{iz+1}  $$
$$  \frac{iz+1}{z+i}  $$